# Buildozer/Kivy: TextInput crashes on numeric input in Android

Tags: python, kivy, buildozer

Noticed the following issue with a Kivy app on Android. The example code is taken from the [Kivy Basic documentation](https://kivy.org/docs/guide/basic.html#customize-the-application):

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput


class LoginScreen(GridLayout):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(LoginScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.cols = 2
        self.add_widget(Label(text='User Name'))
        self.username = TextInput(multiline=False)
        self.add_widget(self.username)
        self.add_widget(Label(text='password'))
        self.password = TextInput(password=True, multiline=False)
        self.add_widget(self.password)


class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return LoginScreen()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

I'm using the new P4A toolchain (`$buildozer -v android_new debug deploy run`). Here's my configuration for building the app:

- Python: 2.7.6
- Kivy: 1.9.2
- buildozer: 0.33dev

The app works fine, but crashes as soon as any number `(0-9)` is entered. Characters `(a-z)`, even special characters, work perfectly. No issues with on desktop (Ubuntu 14.04).

This was tested both on Android 6.0.1 and Android 5.1.1 (separate devices).

Here's the output of `$adb logcat|grep python` (last few lines only):

```
03-07 10:19:48.972  7842  7857 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max units <16>
03-07 10:19:48.976  7842  7857 I python  : [INFO   ] [Window      ] auto add sdl2 input provider
03-07 10:19:48.978  7842  7857 I python  : [INFO   ] [Window      ] virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not docked
03-07 10:19:48.981  7842  7857 W linker  : /data/data/org.test.textinput_tester/files/app/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jnius/jnius.so: is missing DT_SONAME will use basename as a replacement: "jnius.so"
03-07 10:19:49.379  7842  7857 I python  : [WARNING] [Base        ] Unknown <android> provider
03-07 10:19:49.379  7842  7857 I python  : [INFO   ] [Base        ] Start application main loop
03-07 10:19:49.383  7842  7857 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] NPOT texture support is available
03-07 10:19:49.386  7842  7857 I python  : [ERROR  ] [Base        ] Failed to import "android" module. Could not remove android presplash.
03-07 10:20:14.940  7842  7857 I python  : [INFO   ] [Base        ] Leaving application in progress...
03-07 10:20:14.941  7842  7857 I python  :  Traceback (most recent call last):
03-07 10:20:14.942  7842  7857 I python  :    File "/home/guru/EclipseWorkspace1/ScratchArea/.buildozer/android/app/main.py", line 27, in <module>
03-07 10:20:14.944  7842  7857 I python  :    File "/home/guru/EclipseWorkspace1/ScratchArea/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/textinput_tester/private/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kivy/app.py", line 828, in run
03-07 10:20:14.946  7842  7857 I python  :    File "/home/guru/EclipseWorkspace1/ScratchArea/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/textinput_tester/private/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kivy/base.py", line 504, in runTouchApp
03-07 10:20:14.947  7842  7857 I python  :    File "/home/guru/EclipseWorkspace1/ScratchArea/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/textinput_tester/private/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kivy/core/window/window_sdl2.py", line 658, in mainloop
03-07 10:20:14.948  7842  7857 I python  :    File "/home/guru/EclipseWorkspace1/ScratchArea/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/textinput_tester/private/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kivy/core/window/window_sdl2.py", line 580, in _mainloop
03-07 10:20:14.950  7842  7857 I python  :  AttributeError: 'LogFile' object has no attribute 'encoding'
03-07 10:20:15.002  7842  7857 I python  : Python for android ended.
```

Any help in this regard would be appreciated.